# Jquery/Javascript not working in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, opera

Sooo,.. following script works fine in Firefox and IE, but the drop downs won't show on category 2 in Chrome and Opera.

Can't seem to find the error.

HTML:

```
<select name="category1" id="category1">
    <option value="">Please select first...</option>
    <option value="glass" name="Glass">Glass</option>
    <option value="wood" name="Teak">Teak</option>
    <option value="wood" name="American Oak">American Oak</option>
    <option value="wood" name="American White Ash">American White Ash</option>
    <option value="wood" name="American Walnut">American Walnut</option>
    <option value="wood" name="Merbau">Merbau</option>
    <option value="wood" name="Nyatoh">Nyatoh</option>
</select>

<select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2" >
    <option rel="glass" value="">Please select...</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="">Please select...</option>
                            <!-- Glass -->
    <option rel="glass" value="2X" name="2X">2X</option>
    <option rel="glass" value="Triangle" name="Triangle">Triangle</option>
    <option rel="glass" value="Side-U" name="Side-U">Side-U</option>
                            <!-- Wood -->
    <option rel="wood" value="2X" name="2X">2X</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Triangle" name="Triangle">Triangle</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Side-U" name="Side-U">Side-U</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Trapez" name="Trapez">Trapez</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Rectangle" name="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Mild-Z" name="Mild-Z">Mild-Z</option>
    <option rel="wood" value="Spread-U" name="Spread-U">Spread-U</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT (external file - gets called):

```
  $(function() 
{
    $("#category1").on('change', function() 
    {
        var cat1 = $("#category1");
        var cat2 = $("#category2");
        var cat1value = cat1.val();
        if (cat1value === '')
        {
            cat2.val('').prop('selected', true);
            cat2.html(options).prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if (!$(this).data('options')) 
        {
            $(this).data('options', $('#category2 option').clone());
        }
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[rel=' + id + ']');
        if (options.length) 
        {
            cat2.val('').prop('selected', true);
            cat2.html(options).prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else 
        {
            cat2.html($('<option value>No subcategory found</option>')).prop('disabled', true);
        } 
    });

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any error in your browser console?

Comment: works for me in Fiddle.

Comment: have you looked into using `removeAttr()` instead of `prop()`

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: SORRY & THX! Had an old CSS class I had forgotten about that was hiding the options.